# Sum of other column's value on for continuous duplicate column's data in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I need to add duration value for only continuous column's data. Suppose Execute data coming 3 times in this table and each time it is coming 3 times, 2 times and 1 times. So I want to add duration column's data 3 times as per continuous of state column. 
What I need here that execute will show only 1 time instead of continuous as 3 times and again same rule for 2nd execute which is showing 2 times so it will also display 1 time with cumulative sum of duration column's value. So each iterate rows will come with sum of duration value and show as single row

```
CREATE TABLE Tools
    ([ID] int, [StartDatetime] varchar, [EndDatetime] varchar, [duration] int,  [durationDatetime] varchar, [state] varchar(50), [stateCode] int)
;

INSERT INTO Tools
    ([ID], [StartDatetime], [EndDatetime], [duration],  [durationDatetime], [state], [stateCode])
VALUES

(1367, '2018-03-15 10:02:52', '2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000', 100, '1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000', 'Execute', 6),
(1367, '2018-03-15 10:02:52', '2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000', 900, '1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000', 'Execute', 6),
(1367, '2018-03-15 10:02:52', '2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000', 400, '1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000', 'Execute', 6),
(1367, '2018-03-15 10:02:52', '2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000', 1000, '1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000', 'other', 2),
(1367, '2018-03-15 10:02:52', '2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000', 50, '1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000', 'Execute', 6),
(1367, '2018-03-15 10:02:52', '2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000', 52, '1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000', 'Execute', 6),
(1367, '2018-03-15 10:02:52', '2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000', 8, '1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000', 'other', 2),
(1367, '2018-03-15 10:02:52', '2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000', 4, '1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000', 'other', 2),
(1367, '2018-03-15 10:02:52', '2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000', 740, '1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000', 'Execute', 6)
```

[image]

Comment: Your question implies an order but there is nothing in your data to use for consistent ordering. And from what I can tell your desired output is exactly the same as the sample data.

Comment: Are you storing dates as varchar?

Comment: yes there no unique data order is available but requirement is that I need output as only sum of duration column value for each continuous of execute state and it will show without continuous of duplicate row for execute.

Comment: There is no concept of order in a table. Order comes when you provide an order by statement. You have nothing in your data for that. And as McNets elluded. You should store datetime data in the datetime datatype...that is kind of what it is for. And using varchar with no scale is a bad coding practice. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: no it is type as date time, but for example, I used here as varchar

Comment: if you want then change their data type , I will manage later

Comment: I don't care about the datatype for your question. The problem is you have nothing to order by. All of your datetime values are identical. As such there is no "continuous". This sounds a lot like a typical islands and gaps problem.

Comment: actually each datetime is different for second and minutes but I took here same values. I will edit it with exact date time value

Comment: Sean, forget about date, just take 3 column id (which is same for each row), duration and state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, I also got this scenario and found solution with this snippet.

```
  select grp, value, min(id), max(id), count(*) as cnt
    from (select t.*, (row_number() over (order by id) - row_number() over partition by value order by id)
         ) as grp
    from table t
   ) t
  group by grp, value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added a KID column (identity), as Sean Lange has pointed out you need an order.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Tools
> (
>     [KID] int identity,
>     [ID] int, 
>     [StartDatetime] varchar(50), 
>     [EndDatetime] varchar(50), 
>     [duration] int,  
>     [durationDatetime] varchar(50), 
>     [state] varchar(50), 
>     [stateCode] int
> );
> GO
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Tools ([ID], [StartDatetime], [EndDatetime], [duration],  [durationDatetime], [state], [stateCode]) VALUES
> (1367, '2018-03-15 10:02:52', '2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000', 100, '1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000', 'Execute', 6),
> (1367, '2018-03-15 10:02:52', '2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000', 900, '1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000', 'Execute', 6),
> (1367, '2018-03-15 10:02:52', '2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000', 400, '1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000', 'Execute', 6),
> (1367, '2018-03-15 10:02:52', '2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000', 1000, '1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000', 'other', 2),
> (1367, '2018-03-15 10:02:52', '2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000', 50, '1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000', 'Execute', 6),
> (1367, '2018-03-15 10:02:52', '2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000', 52, '1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000', 'Execute', 6),
> (1367, '2018-03-15 10:02:52', '2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000', 8, '1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000', 'other', 2),
> (1367, '2018-03-15 10:02:52', '2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000', 4, '1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000', 'other', 2),
> (1367, '2018-03-15 10:02:52', '2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000', 740, '1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000', 'Execute', 6);
> GO
> ```

> ```
> ;with r as
> (
>     select * 
>            ,case when coalesce(lag(state) over (partition by ID order by KID), '') <> state then 1 end as reset
>     from   tools
> ), g as
>  (
>      select *, sum(reset) over (order by KID) as grp
>      from r
>      where state = 'Execute'
>  )
>  select ID, StartDatetime, EndDatetime, duration, durationDatetime, state, stateCode, 
>         sum(duration) over (partition by grp order by KID) CumulativeSum
>  from g
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>   ID | StartDatetime       | EndDatetime                 | duration | durationDatetime            | state   | stateCode | CumulativeSum
> ---: | :------------------ | :-------------------------- | -------: | :-------------------------- | :------ | --------: | ------------:
> 1367 | 2018-03-15 10:02:52 | 2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000 |      100 | 1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000 | Execute |         6 |           100
> 1367 | 2018-03-15 10:02:52 | 2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000 |      900 | 1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000 | Execute |         6 |          1000
> 1367 | 2018-03-15 10:02:52 | 2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000 |      400 | 1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000 | Execute |         6 |          1400
> 1367 | 2018-03-15 10:02:52 | 2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000 |       50 | 1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000 | Execute |         6 |            50
> 1367 | 2018-03-15 10:02:52 | 2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000 |       52 | 1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000 | Execute |         6 |           102
> 1367 | 2018-03-15 10:02:52 | 2018-03-15T10:19:32.7000000 |      740 | 1900-01-01T00:16:39.7800000 | Execute |         6 |           740
>
> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5b521f9bcb41f8d14db50a1cb8bf4c0d)*

Comment: Thanks McNets, What I need here that execute will show only 1 time instead of continuous as 3 times and again same rule for 2nd execute which is showing 2 times so it will also display 1 time with cumulative sum. So each iterate rows will come with sum of duration value and show as single row.